# Unable to get PIE to work for border-radius in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I have this in my CSS:

```css
.myAwesomeElement {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    zoom: 1;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
    background: #6699CC;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

I have this in my HTML

```
 <input type="button" class="myAwesomeElement" value="#myAwesomeElement" onClick="">
```

The `PIE.htc` file is on the root directory with the HTML file.

When I view this in IE8, the button displays but it does not have rounded edges.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is in a CSS file which is in a folder coming off the root.

Answer (score 1):

File paths in CSS are relative to the stylesheet, not the root.

Try:

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work either. I have read, with PIE, the file path is not to be relative from the CSS file but from the HTML file.

Comment: @cryztal6 I don't think so. It's a htc file, and there is no specific rule for PIE. /PIE.htc looks correct if your file is actually in the root.

Comment: Open up your debugger and see if you get a 404 of the .htc file when the page loads.

Comment: I am using the debugger in Chrome. I don't see any error message regarding the HTC file under the console tab. Of course the border-radius works fine in Chrome, I am having the issue with IE8. I am not sure if I am looking in the right place in the debugger. It says 'failed to load resource' on some images, so I think I am.